# how to use multiplechoice in Django forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to display forms for my project using CheckboxSelectMultiple, but form displays nothing

This is my forms.py

```
class ItemForExhibitionForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.artist_id = kwargs.pop('artist_id')
    super(ItemForExhibitionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['name'].queryset = Item.objects.all()
    
class Meta:
    model = Item
    fields = ['name',]
    widgets = {'name' : forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()}
```

And it is my views.py

```
else: #GET
        form = ExhibitionEntryForm()
        artist_id = Artist.objects.get(user_id = request.user.id).id
        form2 = ItemForExhibitionForm(artist_id = artist_id)
        return render(request, 'exhibition_entry.html', {'form' : form, 'form2' : form2})
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PEu8.png)

how to display form checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

i am sure, you are forget in template render `form.media`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/media/

CheckboxSelectMultiple use js  to create own widget.

in your template before form render add:

```
<-- in your html template  -->
{{ form.media }}
<form >
    {{ form.as_p}}
</ form>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it isn't working. This is my template code:
<h1>Entry</h1>
        {{ form.media }}
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {{ form.media }}
            {{ form2.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="admit">
        </form>
Or should I use CreateView Class rather than function view?

Comment: I just add code on __init__ that self.fields['name'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=queryset) and it displayed without form.media. Anyway I appreciated for your answer